# Which condition will guarantee the function convergence from integration convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I have a problem about the condition when the integration convergence can lead to function convergence.
Specifically, I am no sure whether the following statement is true. If it is not true, what condition is required to make it become true?

> For the Lebesgue integration, if we assume the function sequences $f_n(x)$ satisfy $\int f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$, then we will have $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere.

For the general case, this statement seems not true. The counter example is that we let
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} x, ~~~~|x| \le n\\
0, ~ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Intuitively, when $f_n(x)$ is non-negative, the statement may be true. How can this be strictly proved? Moreover, is there any other conditions for $f_n(x)$ which make the statement become true?

Comment: That is not a counterexample for the Lebesgue integral since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)|\,dx=\infty$ for all $n\ne 0$.

Comment: If you have $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$, then you do have a subsequence $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e. But even the positiveness of $f_n$ cannot guarantee $f_n \to f$ a.e.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After I check it, I think you are right. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true even when the functions can be nonnegative. A counterexample would be the typewriter sequence of functions $f_n = 1_{[\frac{n-2^k}{2^k},\frac{n-2^k+1}{2^k}]}$ when $k\ge 0$ and $2^k\le n < 2^{k+1}$. Then $\int f_n \to 0$ but $f_n$ does not converge pointwise to $0$ anywhere in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. If we relax the convergence to almost everywhere, i.e., $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ a.e., does the non-negative condition guarantee the function convergence?

Comment: @ZHANGWei: No, with the same counterexample of functions. The typewriter sequence is identically $0$ outside of $[0,1]$, so it converges to $0$ there, but for every $x\in [0,1]$, $f_n(x)$ does not converge, so there is a whole interval of points where the sequence does not converge, and in particular it does not converge a.e.